# Merge elements into one huge array in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am working on a javascript program and i'll need to merge the below multidimensional array into one array

```
array = [
    [ '78161701,20221101,20221108' ]
    [ '76450406,20221101,20221108' ]
    [ '76450047,20221101,20221108' ]
    [ '76450111,20221101,20221108' ]
    [ '72606489,20221101,20221108' ]
    [ '79557102,20221101,20221108' ]
]
```

This is my expected outcome

```
array = [
    '78161701,20221101,20221108',
    '76450406,20221101,20221108',
    '76450047,20221101,20221108',
    '76450111,20221101,20221108',
    '72606489,20221101,20221108',
    '79557102,20221101,20221108'
 ]
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: Your “expected outcome” is invalid. Does your original array really have single-element arrays inside?

Comment: array = [
    '78161701,20221101,20221108',
    '76450406,20221101,20221108',
    '76450047,20221101,20221108',
    '76450111,20221101,20221108',
    '72606489,20221101,20221108',
    '79557102,20221101,20221108'
 ]

This is actually the expected outcome

Comment: Please clarify if you want your outcome to contain quote marks or not.

Comment: It should contain quote marks

Comment: When you are asking help from volunteers, posting compilable input, output and the code you've tried is the absolute bare minimum. The input is missing commas. Why did the output suddenly change?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
    [ '78161701,20221101,20221108' ],
    [ '76450406,20221101,20221108' ],
    [ '76450047,20221101,20221108' ],
    [ '76450111,20221101,20221108' ],
    [ '72606489,20221101,20221108' ],
    [ '79557102,20221101,20221108' ]
];
console.log(array.flat());
```